# How can I use do auxiliary verb in indirection question sentence?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, interrogatives, do-support

Can we use do-auxillity verb in indirection question sentence.

For example, Is this right?

Why is the sky blue?-> Why the sky do blue? Or Why the water do exchange to air on 100 degree?

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the sky blue?

The indicative version would be

> The sky **is** blue.

..here, the sky is ascribed a property ("blue"). "Blue" is not a verb, it's an adjective. If you write

> Why does the sky blue? (WRONG)

.. you'll make it seem as if it's a verb. "The sky started *to blue*". But there is no single-word verb meaning "to blue" in English.

The proper way would be to say:

> Why **is** the sky blue?

or

> Why **does** the sky **look** blue? (as Catija wrote).

With **do**, you need a verb like **look**, not an adjective like **blue**.

---

In your second sentence, you have a verb ("**turn** to steam"), so you can use the so-called "do-support":

> Why **does** water **turn** to steam at 100C?

---

Related reading:

- [Copular constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) - Wikipedia (about sentences like "The sky is blue")
- [Do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) - Wikipedia (when and how to use **do** as an auxiliary)

Answer (score 3):

In your specific examples, you can say:

`Why does the sky look blue?`

`Why does water turn to steam [or evaporate/vaporize] at 100 degrees C.` -This statement actually wouldn't be correct with `is`.

`Do` generally can't be used to replace `is`.